# Can't load geojson file using geopandas

Tags: python, geojson, gdal, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to load geojson file into Jupyter notebook, using

```
import geopandas as gpd

country = gpd.read_file(r"‪path-to-file\svn_border.geojson")
```

It returns following error:

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError: '‪‪path-to-file\svn_border.geojson' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

fiona\ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

fiona\_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: '‪‪path-to-file\svn_border.geojson' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

I am using Python 3.6.8, Fiona 1.18, GDAL 3.1.4. Even when I tried to upload content of geojson file as json format, it gives the same error.

I have been working on the same error for several days now, could anyone  point my mistake?

Edit: After trying to validate geojson files which I have, it turned out that they are corrupt. I have used an example geojson file, which worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you pass the correct path? This error indicates the issue with path.

Comment: I have used with another file, this time pretty sure path is correct:
fiona\ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start() fiona_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector() DriverError: '‪path-to-file\svn_border.geojson' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: Can you try using `import os` and `os.path.exists('./path/to/your/file/svn_border.json')` ?